# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt

Tags: java, android, encryption

I try to encrypt and decrypt email and password text.I used javax.crypto library. It encrypt data correclty and without error. But while it decrypt data,  throws errors like below.       What did I miss?

```
private final String key = "12345678901234567890123456789012";

private void saveUserInfo() {
    String email = emailET.getText().toString();
    String password = passwordET.getText().toString();

   SecretKeySpec sks = generateKey();
    byte[] encodedEmail = encrypt(email, sks);
    byte[] encodedPassword = encrypt(password, sks);

    String decodedEmail = decrypt(encodedEmail, sks);
    String decodedPassword = decrypt(encodedPassword, sks);

    Log.d("Encoded Email", Base64.encodeToString(encodedEmail, Base64.DEFAULT));
    Log.d("Encoded Password", Base64.encodeToString(encodedPassword, Base64.DEFAULT));

    Log.d("Decoded Email", decodedEmail);
    Log.d("Decoded Password", decodedPassword);
}

public SecretKeySpec generateKey(){
        try {
            SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
            KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            keyGenerator.init(256, secureRandom);
            SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
            return sks;
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException error){
            return null;
        }
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(String text, Key key){
        try {
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] encodedBytes = c.doFinal(text.getBytes());
            return encodedBytes;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String decrypt(byte[] text, Key key){
        try {
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] decodedBytes = c.doFinal(text);
            return new String(decodedBytes);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**StackTrace :**

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.EVP_CipherFinal_ex(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.doFinalInternal(OpenSSLCipher.java:430)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.engineDoFinal(OpenSSLCipher.java:466)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1340)
    at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.decrypt(MainActivity.java:100)
    at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.saveUserInfo(MainActivity.java:53)
    at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onSubmitButtonClicked(MainActivity.java:40)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.EVP_CipherFinal_ex(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.doFinalInternal(OpenSSLCipher.java:430)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.engineDoFinal(OpenSSLCipher.java:466)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1340)
    at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.decrypt(MainActivity.java:100)
    at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.saveUserInfo(MainActivity.java:54)
    at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onSubmitButtonClicked(MainActivity.java:40)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: You need an IV for CBC mode.

Comment: How to do it?  ....